# Android Volley - orientation changes

Tags: android, android-networking, android-volley

How can we deal with orientation changes, `Activities`/`Fragments` stoping / resuming using `Volley` ?

I know that for `GET` requests, the response will be cached and the second time we attempt to make that request, we will get a cached response.(IF the server sends the proper HTTP headers)

But what about `POST`? Suppose I make a `POST` requests (i.e. register, which I want to happen only once), my app goes to background, request is finished while app is still in background, and then I go back to the app. How do I get the `Response` for that `Request`, or how do I re-connect to it, if it still pending?

AFAIK there is pretty much no support for this in `Volley`. Am I right? Is there an easy way to solve the above mentioned scenario, using `Volley`?

Comment: "How do I get the Response for that Request, or how do I re-connect to it, if it still pending?" -- just because your app is no longer in the foreground does not prevent threads from running. What makes you think that the `Request` was not already delivered to you? Use a retained fragment for asynchronous operations, so that way regardless of orientation changes, your asynchronous operations have a stable base to communicate to.

Comment: for some reason I had the impression that `Volley` won't deliver responses if we go to background (like `Robospice`), but you are right. We have to call `requestQueue.cancel(...)` to stop the delivery. I'm still thinking of a nice simple way of dealing with re-delivering responses properly during `stop/resume`.

Answer (score 8):

Volley doesn't provide a mechanism for this out of the box, but you can look into Square's Otto library for Android, it is made to handle situations like yours elegantly.

Implement the Listener for the Volley request so that it posts a successful response onto the Bus, wrapped in an event object like "RegisterEventSuccess" (you define this yourself). Let your Activities or Fragments subscribe to this event type with Otto's @Subscribe mechanism. If - for example - one Activity launches the Volley request and dies because of a screen orientation change, another Activity instance (also registered to the Otto bus) can then receive the event that contains the response of the Volley request.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: This solution definitely sounds interesting. Is there a place you have implemented this. Have you encountered any issues?

Comment: Not to reopen a dead question but I was looking for some examples of Volley + Otto for request/response management, and this guy put together a pretty clean example of a melding of the two

https://github.com/tslamic/AndroidExamples/tree/master/HttpBinVolley

Comment: Using this solution, how would you handle the possibility of the network response returning in the moment that the activities are transitioning (between onDestroy of the first activity, and onCreate of the newly oriented one)? Here, neither of the activities will be registered to the bus and awaiting the event. The @Producer methods may address this, but they don't really seem suited to work as a generic network cache and don't really align with the original pattern.

Comment: @kyle-ivey : I have a solution to that in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23686294/507339 . It is _a_ solution, but probably not the only one. PS: I considered the `Producer`-method first, but discarded it because it did not fit my pattern.

Answer (score 4):

I have now attempted to address the concern of @kyle-ivey in that responses arriving in between `onPause()` and `onResume()` are discarded. This is a real issue as I have experienced it in a live application.

My approach builds on the event bus pattern implemented in the answer by Thomas Moerman, although I've reimpemented an example application from scratch. It depends on the [Otto Event bus Library](http://square.github.io/otto/), [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley). It is implemented in IntelliJ 13 Ultimate using Maven tom resolve the dependencies.

**Solution:** I add to the previous answers a class which acts as a HTTP Response Buffer which takes over the responsibility of listening to events while the Activity is transitioning. When done, the activity actively polls for any responses that may have arrived while the activity was disconnected to the event bus. It hooks on/off in the `onPause` and `onResume`-events next to the event-bus registering in a fashion like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ServiceLocator.ResponseBuffer.startSaving(); // The buffer takes over
    ServiceLocator.EventBus.unregister(this);    // Unregistering with Otto
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ServiceLocator.EventBus.register(this);         // Re-registering
    ServiceLocator.ResponseBuffer.stopAndProcess(); // Process any responses buffered
}
```

Here is the implementation of [the ResponseBuffer-class](https://github.com/Nilzor/OttoVolleyDoneRight/blob/master/src/nilzor/ottovolley/core/OttoGsonResponseBuffer.java).

**Caveat 1**: If the activity is never resumed, and neither `stopAndProcess()` nor `stopAndPurge()` is called in any future activity, the buffer may be a source of memory leak. Be aware of how you use it. A safe pattern would be to have `stopAndProcess()` in  `onResume()` in *all* of your activites.

**Caveat 2**: It is not thread-safe. If there is to come a context switch on the line between where it stars saving and it unregisters the event bus, it may receive the event twice or zero times.

The example includes some test code in the form of UI and support classes, but the main classes you would need if you want to utilize this pattern in a separate projects are the ones in the following packages:

- nilzor.ottovolley.core
- nilzor.ottovolley.messages

See the github-repository [OttoVolleyDoneRight](https://github.com/Nilzor/OttoVolleyDoneRight) for a complete example with UI for testing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple solution that solved my problem with downloading data from network using Volley library. If your app uses fragments due to Google's recomendations, than everything you should do to prevent crashing if user rotates the screen while loading data is put `setRetainInstance(true);` in `onCreateView` method of your fragment(-s).

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_studios, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    lvStudios = (ListView) theView.findViewById(R.id.lvStudios);
  return theView;
}
```

Comment: Very old topic, but yet this is the best pattern

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have login button,On click of Btn your calling server through volley,Suddenly if screen Orientation changes,the volley restart,and app crashes..

so My solution is:on click of Btn first lock screen Orientation,when Volley response comes you Unlock Screen Orientation...

...........here
on click---lockDeviceRotation(true)    //Lock
on Response--lockDeviceRotation(false) //Unlock

```
public void lockDeviceRotation(boolean value) {
    if (value) {
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        }
    } else {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
        }
    }
}
```